# WIndows XP: is it possible to schedule tasks just before shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I need to do series of tasks like take backups just before my PC shutsdown. I am not permitted to use any downloaded tool for doing this. So my idea is to use batch files to do these repeat tasks.

My question:

is it possible to schedule tasks in windows XP just before shutdown? I donot find any option in the scheudle tasks dialog though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have XP Pro, you there is a place in the local group policy editor (gpedit.msc) to add batchfiles to be run on shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of [this article](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/group_policy_editor.htm) explain how to do that by changing policies.